# Log4J How to set log FOLDER (KEY) on NTEventLogAppender

Tags: java, log4j, logging, event-viewer

I've created a appender of the type NTEventLogAppender like this:

```
log4j.appender.EVA=org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender
#log4j.appender.EVA.log=TestLog
log4j.appender.EVA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.EVA.source=TestSource
log4j.appender.EVA.layout.ConversionPattern=[%c][%l][%p][%thread]: %m%n
```

As you can see, on the comented line I tried to set the log TestLog, so that the log error get stored on a specific Event Viewer Log for my application, instead of the Event Viewr default Application Log.

If I uncoment a line I an error sayng that the log property doesn't exist:

```
**log4j:WARN No such property [log] in org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender.**
```

Is it even possible to do this as it is using Log4Net?

Thanks

Comment: What the hell? Do you mean that Log4Net allows you to do this and Log4j doesn't? Just a simple yes or no would do ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in log4j:

> **Why can't I map my logger names to the loggers that appear in the NT
>   Event Log when I use the NTEventLogAppender?**
>
> Unfotunately, the logger names are hardcoded within the message
>   resource DLL (see previous question about NTEventLogAppender), so
>   there isn't any easy way to override those dynamically... in fact, I
>   don't think it's possible to do it, as you'd have to modify the DLL
>   resources for every application. Since most native applications don't
>   use the Logger column anyway...

Source: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a2.10